# How to put inside Facebook message feed "profile link" used API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

How to put inside Facebook message feed "profile link" used API ?

For now I have prepared this code:

```
$request = $this->fb->post('/'.$this->pageId.'/feed', [
    'message' => "
        I'ves been testing my IQ! @facebook \n\t
        #test #testt #testowy\n\t                
        http://www.example.com
    ",
    'name' => 'Some title',
    'caption' => 'some caption',
    'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
    'actions' => json_encode(array('name'=>'Some name','link'=>'http://www.example.com')),
    'description' => 'Some description @example',
    'picture' => 'http://www.example.com/image.jpg'
]);
```

published post view:

[published post view (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMbyv.png)

It looks nice but I'd like change **@facebook** to link to **profile link** to look like this:

[published post view after changes (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmB3J.png)

Some advice, how to make this?

Comment: You are aware that the user needs to type the message. You are not allowed to write it

Comment: Only pages can tag other pages in their posts, and it needs to get reviewed as well. How to do it, is explained in the /page/feed documentation.

Comment: @CBroe I know but I can't find this in doc ;/ If you know how to make this - can you write me some example ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/page/feed#publish

Comment: Thanks @CBroe this is what I was looking for.